# How to set up ssl ceritficate for react.cordova, ionic and android?

Tags: android, reactjs, cordova, ssl

Help!
Im complete Beginner in developing apps for android or ios.

I started with ionic, react, cordova. I found nice tutorials how to set up ssl on angular but can not find something like that for react.

How can I set it up?

Is it in package.json or ...

Answer (score 0):

The following article describe step by step how to configure ssl certificate.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/02/web-security-policy-changes-for-android-app-publish-apps#app_ssltls
I followed the steps and this is the answer:
Create a file called index.html in www and then add the following in the file.

```
<script src="https://js.ssl.google-analytics.com/burch.js"></script>
<script src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/gms_analytics.js"></script>
```

Important: in order to have the JS execution in the browser, you need to add the files in www directory.
If you are using an external server then just the following

> 

This will get the Google analytics JS code to load.
If the JS code is not loading in your browser. Then it means that the server is blocking access from this external IP address.
Go to your server manager like aws, azure, google.
Then go to the server properties page and check this box.

Block access for unsafe protocols.

If the box is uncheck then the JS code in your browser will load in a second.

Comment: Hi, sorry but the site is not available :( and I have own certificates .. so i don need them from google .. i just dont know where should it be set it up in react